# Least Common Multiple Using While Loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to find the LCM of two numbers, using a while loop. I've searched and many answers use the GCF to find the LCM but is there a way to find the LCM without finding the GCF first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below code.

```
public class Test 
{


    static int lcm(int x, int y)
    {
        int a;
        a = (x > y) ? x : y; // a is greater number
        while(true)
        {
            if(a % x == 0 && a % y == 0)
                return a;
            ++a;
        }   
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the two numbers: ");
        int x = input.nextInt();
        int y = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The LCM of two numbers is: " + lcm(x, y));
        input.close();      
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you think OP could use his favorite search engine [to find the program from which you copied](http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-find-gcd-lcm-two-numbers/) without attribution?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i don't know how i missed that link searching before, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

A more optimized version of other users code:

```
static int lcm(int x, int y)
{
    int a;
    a = (x > y) ? x : y; // a is the greater number
    int b = a;
    while(true)
    {
        if(a % x == 0 && a % y == 0)
            return a;
        a = a + b;
    }   
}
```